# TinyMCE add item to context menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, contextmenu, menuitem

I want to add a new menu item to TinyMCE's context menu, and perform a command when the user clicks it, so far i have this, which is not working:

```
tinyMCE.init({
...

setup : function(ed) {
    ed.onContextMenu.add(function(ed, menu) {
        menu.add({title : 'Menu 1', onclick : function() {
            alert('Item 1 was clicked.');
        }});
    });
}
```

The code above throws an error saying "menu.add is not a function", if i remove the menu.add stuff and place a console.log(menu), it returns "contextmenu" upon opening the context menu.

What would be the right way to add an item to the context menu ? Preferably without having to modify the plugin itself. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need something like

```
ed.onContextMenu.add(function(ed, e) {

if (!e.ctrlKey) {

    // Restore the last selection since it was removed
    if (lastRng)
        ed.selection.setRng(lastRng);

    var menu = this._getMenu(ed);

    if ((typeof menu).toLowerCase() == 'object')
    {
        menu.showMenu(e.clientX, e.clientY);

        Event.add(ed.getDoc(), 'click', function(e) {
            hide(ed, e);
        });
        Event.cancel(e);
    }
}

});
```

and the function _getMenu where you may insert contextmenu options:

```
//example this will only display if an image was clicked
if (node !== "undefined" && node.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'img') {

m.add({
    title: 'my menu',
});


m.addSeparator();

// Inline-Element editieren
m.add({
    title: 'to be choosen1',
    icon: 'http://...',
    cmd: 'undo'
});

t.onContextMenu.dispatch(t, m, el, col);

return m;
}
```

**EDIT:**

you can get the default menu using (the plugin contextmenu needs to be active)

```
var editor = tinymce.get(editor_id);
var menu = editor.plugins.contextmenu._getMenu(editor);
```

adding an entry to the menu should work as follows

```
menu.add({title : 'undo', icon : 'undo', cmd : 'Undo'});
```

it might be necessary to render the menu explicitly using `showMenu`.
Another way to insert a menu to the contextemenu is to modify the editor_plugin.js in the tiny_mce/plugins/contextemneu directory and add the entry directly. You may also copy the plugin, modify and rename it - let it work as a custom plugin.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it helped understanding it. After tweaking you're code i got it to open a new dropmenu with items inside, but i want to just add an item to the default context menu, instead of creating a new one. Is that possible ? I can't seem to get a reference to that default dropmenu? how can i do that ?

Comment: glad to have been able to help

Comment: @taha: this should still work - even with newer tinymce versions. what have you done so far? be aware that you will fill in your own editor_id!

Comment: **EDIT 2:** *(by [Nicolas](http://stackoverflow.com/users/753113/nicolas))* I have written a response on TinyMCE's forum to tackle customising the context menu 'on the fly' (after initialisation) for TinyMCE version 4.1.9 - see my response on this page: http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=116109#p116109. Apologies for not making this a comment, I don't have enough reputation yet to comment!

Answer (score 0):

You can add context menu like this:

```
setup : function(ed) {
    ed.onContextMenu.add(function(ed, menu) {
        displayContextMenu(ed,e);
        }});
    });
}

function displayContextMenu(ed,e){
    var m = ed.plugins.contextmenu._getMenu(ed);
    m.add({title : 'advanced.bold_desc', icon : 'bold', cmd : 'bold'});
}
```